ASP.NET Core 8 Web API + Ajax call to controller: Completely disable Cors
I created a website with API using .NET 8 and Razor, and I'm hosting my website using AWS Elastic Beanstalk.
My website allows to create and save tests, and it works just perfectly from my side, not only in dev mode, but the published prod version.
One person from India is trying to help me to load tests, but it is getting Cors related errors constantly. No matter what I try to disable Cors, it always receives an error when hitting "Save".
Whatever I try - from different SO threads - always leads to a different error, each longer and more confusing.
This is my jQuery Ajax call to save:
function saveTest() {
    var test = generateTestJson(true);

    if (test == Result.KO) 
        return false;

    toastMessage(Texts.processingData, InformationState.INFORMATION, true, Config.informationTimeout);

    var saveMode = SaveMode.Insert;

    if (selectedTestId != "") {   // Update
        saveMode = SaveMode.Update;
        testId = selectedTestId
    } else {   // Save
        //check for duplicates
        var testName = document.getElementById("Name").value;
        var testExists = ddlItemExists("ddlTests", testName);

        if (testExists) {
            toastMessage(Texts.testAlreadyExists.replace("%0", testName), InformationState.ERROR, false, Config.informationTimeout);
            return;
        }
    }

    var deletedElements = generateJsonDeletedElements();

    formData.delete('test');
    formData.delete('saveMode');
    formData.delete('deletedElements');
    //
    formData.append('test', test);
    formData.append('saveMode', saveMode);
    formData.append('deletedElements', deletedElements);

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Test/SaveTest',
        method: 'POST',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: formData,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.status == Result.OK) {
                selectedTestId = testId;
                formSubmitted = true;
                fillTestSelector();
            }
            showResultStatus(data.status, data.message);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            clearTimeout(informationTimer);
            showToast(xhr.responseText, InformationState.ERROR, false, true, "3");
        }
    })
}

Program.cs:
// ...
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
   options.AddPolicy("MyPolicy",
       policy =>
       {
           policy
               .AllowAnyOrigin()
               .AllowAnyMethod()
               .AllowAnyHeader()
               .SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true); // allow any origin
       }
   );
});

var app = builder.Build();
    
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseWebOptimizer();

// app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseCors("TestMePolicy");

var locOptions = app.Services.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
app.UseRequestLocalization(locOptions.Value);

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();

Controller:
[HttpPost]
[EnableCors("MyPolicy")]
public async Task<JsonResult> SaveTest(string test, int saveMode, List<IFormFile> files, string deletedElements = "")

The most annoying thing is that it is working just fine from my location in Europe, but my friend is not able to work from India, whenever it hits "Save" a Cors related error is thrown, the controller method is obviously not called.
It is also incomprehensible the fact that from my side it works even without all that Program.cs code to disable Cors, but not from India.
I need to completely disable Cors, and I've checked many SO threads to no avail.

The geographic discrepancy suggests some caching problem. I haven't dug too deep, but this may be due to a subtle bug in ASP.NET's CORS middleware. Try removing .SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true); (which does more harm than good anyway), redeploy and wait for the changes to propagate to your friend in India.

Hello @jub0bs, and thanks for your reply. I'll check it and I'll let you know.

The policy name is different, please double check it.

Suggestions
1. The middleware order is very important, you should change it like below.
var app = builder.Build();
//DELETE IT
//app.UseAuthentication();
//app.UseAuthorization();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseWebOptimizer();

// app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseCors("TestMePolicy");

var locOptions = app.Services.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
app.UseRequestLocalization(locOptions.Value);
//DELETE IT
//app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();

2. If you want to allow all origin , you can set it like below.
    builder.Services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
    {
        builder.AllowAnyMethod()
            .SetIsOriginAllowed(_ => true)
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowCredentials();
    }));
    ...
    app.UseRouting();

    // add this line
    app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");


Hello @Jason Pan, and thanks for your reply. The policy name is consistent everywhere, it is just I was trying to hide my app name as it is sensitive information and forgot to change it in the UseCors, silly mistake. I'll check the rest of the suggestions and I'll let you know how it goes then.

Hi @DiegoPerez Please try to use suggestion 2, it should be work.

Thank you - the first example that when copied and pasted - worked.
